# Is there any way to check the game over condition in each of the timeouts but calling the main function to restart the game by a single function

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am making a game in which I have 5 players each being moved with a `setTimeout` method which repeats after calling another `setTimeout` method.

However, when the game gets over I need to stop all the current timeouts and call the main function to start game again. Since the hero can get killed by touching any of the villains I have to check this condition in their timeouts. If this condition is met in any of the timeout, all timeouts are cleared and main function is called to start game again.

The issue is that many of the timeouts are still going on in the background. Is there any way to check the game over condition in each of the timeouts? I think each timeout ends up calling the main function.

Answer (score 0):

[setTimout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)
returns a timer id that you can use with
[`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout)
to cancel the timer. If you keep track of those ids, you can cancel any
outstanding timers when the game ends.

```js
let npcs = [];

let createNPC = (delay, logic) => {
  // create a function that runs the NPCs logic
  // and then calls setTimeout, storing the timer id
  // as a property of the returned function
  let runLogic = function () {
    logic();
    runLogic.timerId = setTimeout(runLogic, delay);
  };
  // start the NPC running
  runLogic.timerId = setTimeout(runLogic, delay);
  // return a reference to this function so we
  // can store it and use it later
  return runLogic;
};

let gameOver = () => {
  // loop through all the NPC functions and cancel
  // all of their timers
  npcs.forEach(npc => {
    clearTimeout(npc.timerId);
  });
  console.log('Game over');
};

// create new NPCs and store them in the npcs array
npcs.push(createNPC(1000, () => console.log('NPC 1 did something')));
npcs.push(createNPC(1500, () => console.log('NPC 2 did something')));
npcs.push(createNPC(2000, () => console.log('NPC 3 did something')));
npcs.push(createNPC(2200, () => console.log('NPC 4 did something')));

// for the purposes of this demo, just end the game after 10 seconds
setTimeout(gameOver, 10 * 1000);
```

A better approach than tracking a bunch of timers would be to use a single timer that runs the entire game loop. Because we just have a single timer that runs more frequently, I'm using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) instead of `setTimeout`.

```js
let gameLoopTimer;

let npcs = [];

let createNPC = (delay, logic) => {
  let npc = {
    logic: logic,
    delay: delay,
    lastActionAt: Date.now()
  };
  return npc;
};

let gameLoop = () => {
  let now = Date.now();
  npcs.forEach(npc => {
    // if delay ms have passed since our last action, act again
    if (now - npc.lastActionAt >= npc.delay) {
      // run the NPC logic
      npc.logic();
      // update the last action
      npc.lastActionAt = now;
    }
  });
};

let gameOver = () => {
  clearInterval(gameLoopTimer);
  console.log('Game over');
};

let startGameLoop = () => {
  let now = Date.now();
  // reset all of the NPC last actions
  npcs.forEach(npc => npc.lastActionAt = now);
  // start running the game loop
  gameLoopTimer = setInterval(gameLoop, 100);
};

// create new NPCs and store them in the npcs array
npcs.push(createNPC(1000, () => console.log('NPC 1 did something')));
npcs.push(createNPC(1500, () => console.log('NPC 2 did something')));
npcs.push(createNPC(2000, () => console.log('NPC 3 did something')));
npcs.push(createNPC(2200, () => console.log('NPC 4 did something')));

startGameLoop();

// for the purposes of this demo, just end the game after 10 seconds
setTimeout(gameOver, 10 * 1000);
```